# use custom property loader to override struts message

Tags: file-upload, properties, struts2

I have an application with Spring 3 and struts 2. I have my own properties files with custom messages. These files are loaded dynamically with spring while startup. And I use PropertyCache.getMessage() from any where in my code to get those custom messages. These message resources are fully controlled by my application and spring.

Now I have a scenario of file upload. The upload limit is configured in global struts constants and with "fileUpload" interceptors. As per the theory, when a user tries to upload big files the framework will show up its message (i know how to customize it with struts).

Since I am using my own resources, I want to show up my custom message (not going to use "**struts.messages.error.file.too.large**") using my own "PropertyCache.getMessage()" method.

How is it possible to override struts error message so that the framework will pick up the message from my own resource instead of struts constant/struts global properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i do not see any direct solutions to your problem as the above message is being set under the fileUploader interceptor,its quite possible that there might be some more flexible and best solution out there.

For now i can suggest you to create a `FileUploaderInterceptor` and you can use your Spring message reader functionality to read message from your custom message file and replace Struts2 `getTextMessage()` method

1. [FileUploadInterceptor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.1.6/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/FileUploadInterceptor.java)